# Get all worksheets

Tags: c#, .net, excel, epplus

i've got this very strange error while trying to get the worksheets (just worksheet names) from excel (xlsx) file with EPPlus.

```
using (var ep = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(filePath)) {
    foreach (var ws in ep.Workbook.Worksheets)
        ....
}
```

This works flawlesly (why shouldn't it right), but from time to time i find excel file that just throws `System.NullReferenceException` while trying to get worksheets.

Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in EPPlus.dll

The thing that baffles me the most is that when i debug this and go step by step everything works fine.

This is the StackTrace:

```
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRangeBase..ctor(ExcelWorksheet xlWorksheet, String address)
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelNamedRangeCollection.Add(String Name, ExcelRangeBase Range)
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorkbook.GetDefinedNames()
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.get_Workbook()
   at isef.winformapp.Helpers.ExcelUtilities.GetWorksheets(String filePath) ...
```

Im just wondering whether someone has encountered a similar error

You can download and try one of those 'not working' xlsx files [here](http://www.filedropper.com/notworking) if you want to try it yourself.

It's an empty xlsx file with two empty worksheets.

Comment: The debugger causes some objects to be kept alive longer so it's not usual for something like this to not be expressed under the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because there are defined names in the workbook that refer to a sheet/table/range that no longer exists.  [Referenced from here](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/416)

First I was able to duplicate your error.  Second, I deleted these Names and your code worked fine.

[image]

---

Unfortunately, the exception happens anytime you reference the workbook so I see no clear way to solve this outside the package.

```
var wb = ep.Workbook;  //also throws error when wb has invalid names
```